# ASP.NET HTTP POST and Redirect

Tags: http-post, http-get, http-redirect

I have users that will be directed to my application from an external site, and during this redirecting, user's email addresses will be sent to me by HTTP POST.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to receive user's email address, and send the user to the Index view.

I have the following methods:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string email = "";

        string[] keys = Request.Form.AllKeys;
        for (int i = 0; i < keys.Length; i++)
        {
            Response.Write(keys[i] + ": " + Request.Form[keys[i]] + "<br>");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(keys[i] + ": " + Request.Form[keys[i]]);

            email = Request.Form[keys[i]].ToString();
        }

        return Index(email);
    }

 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string email)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

And this is the method I have to mimic the external site's job, which was redirecting user to my view with user's email address.

```
 public ActionResult Httppost()
    {
        using (var wb = new WebClient())
        {
            var data = new NameValueCollection();
            data["email"] = "test@email.com";

            var response = wb.UploadValues("http://localhost:57695/Home/Index", "POST", data);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

The problem is, Index never receives the email address from my Httppost() method, and email is always received as "". How can I receive the email from Httppost() into Index()?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you sending the email address in a *separate request*?  These two requests have nothing to do with one another.  The data received in one isn't available to the other, and they're not guaranteed to happen in the same order.

Instead of this:

```
var response = wb.UploadValues("http://localhost:57695/Home/Index", "POST", data);
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

Just send the value in *one* request so that it will be available in that request:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", new { email = "test@email.com" });
```

Then you only need *one* action:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(string email)
{
    // use the email parameter
}
```

---

Side note: I don't think this is going to do what you expect:

```
return Index(email);
```

That's going to look for a *view* named after the value of the `email` variable.  Because of how method overloading works, you can't really use a `string` by itself as a model.  You're going to want to either set it on an actual model or put it in something like `ViewBag` instead.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I now understand. However, the solution you provided resulted me having the URL bar as the following: http://localhost:57695/?email=test%40email.com . I need to avoid users manipulating the email via query string. Could this be done?

Comment: Actually, I need to send the email as HTTP Post, not via method call. So, return RedirectToAction("Index", new { email = "test@email.com" }); doesn't accomplish the requirements I believe.

Comment: @UğurDinç: A post has to come from the client, not the server.  You'll need a form in the view which posts to the target URL, not a redirect.  Also note that users can manipulate post data almost as easily as query string data.  If you need the data to be "secure" in some way then you need to keep it server-side, perhaps in session or something like that.

Comment: Thank you for all the info once again. From my perspective, I am receiving the data from somewhere else, and I will be keeping it on the server side for validation later on, while also displaying it on the View.